# how to delete carriage returns in html using php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, carriage-return

I'm using a javascript function that receives some html code that was included using php.
It is not html in a php string but an html file with .php extension.

As the html code is sent as a parameter to the js function it can't contain carriage returns. The problem is that writing big blocks of html in a single line is terrible, I would like to have a function only to erase the carriage returns before sending the content.

Is there a source for such a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple

```
echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), null, $htmlCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

by "building it in PHP" I assume you mean that you're building a string which contains the relevant HTML.

If that's the case, then it's a simple matter of not having the carriage returns as a part of your string.

i.e., don't do this:

```
foo =  "  this is my string
         and I have it on two lines";
```

but rather do this

```
foo = "" .
      " this is my string" .
      " and it's on one line ";
```

Sure, you could use a string.replace function, but building via concats means that you get to skip that step.

Comment: I think you mean .= rather than += .

Comment: aye.. i blame the 6 years between now and the last time I wrote any php

Answer (score 1):

When you say "in a PHP file", I assume you mean you're `include()`ing a file that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Foo</title></head>
  <body>
    <?php do_stuff(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

If that's the case, what you're looking for is called [Output Control](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), which allows you to either prevent data from being sent until you're ready or capture it to a string for additional processing.  To strip carriage returns from an included file, you can do this:

```
<?php

ob_start();                       // start buffering output
include("foo.php");               // include your file
$foo = ob_get_contents();         // get a copy of the buffer's contents
ob_clean_end();                   // discard the buffer and turn off buffering
echo str_replace("\r", "", $foo); // print output w/o carriage returns
```

If you want to remove newlines as well, change that last line to:

```
echo str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple [string substitution](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a [XML writer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) for this, if that's what your javascript parses. That way the result will always be valid, and the code should get cleaner.

Comment: In most cases disk I/O is the main bottleneck. I'd do it this way and cache the result.